# Fortran: external function argument has size 0

Tags: function, fortran, external

I have the following code structure:

```
PROGRAM main

  IMPLICIT NONE

  REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: var

  ALLOCATE(var(3))

  var(1) = 1.0d0
  var(2) = 2.0d0
  var(3) = 3.0d0

  CALL f1(var, f2)

  CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE f1(arg_in, fun)

    REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: arg_in
    EXTERNAL fun

    PRINT *, arg_in

    CALL fun(arg_in)

    PRINT *, arg_in

  END SUBROUTINE f1

  SUBROUTINE f2(arg_in)

    REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(INOUT) :: arg_in

    PRINT *, SIZE(arg_in)

    arg_in = 2.0d0 * arg_in

    RETURN

  END SUBROUTINE f2

END PROGRAM main
```

When executing the program I noticed that the size of the array in function f2 is 0. In my real program I have the same problem although I get an error message in contrast to my simple program above:

> Attempt to use pointer F when it is not associated with a target

Could anyone give a hint what might be the problem?

Comment: You cannot get the same error message if you do not use any pointers and the error specifically mentions one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the subroutine as external, but it has an assumed shape dummy argument, therefore it needs an explicit interface, you have to specify one using procedure

```
procedure(f2) :: fun
```

or an interface block

```
interface
  SUBROUTINE fun(arg_in)
    REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(INOUT) :: arg_in
  end
end interface
```

After that you will also realize, that `f2` modifies the array `arg_in`, and therefore it is illegal to reference it from `f1`, which has the array `arg_in` as `intent(in)`.